# PrimeFaces admin theme applies partially

Tags: primefaces

when applying the theme this has no color, it is white on all the pages of the project java ee

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>admin</param-value>
</context-param>
```

those two pages the color of the theme is white

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgVmd.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJlTL.jpg

add to the project admin-theme-1.0.0-RC15 and primefaces-6.2 but it does not work completely, what do I have to do to make this theme work full?

Comment: Please a share a sample (maven) project on Github or in a zip file and I may help you.

Comment: Looking at the images looks like you didn't enabled font-awesome as described in docs here: http://admin-showcase-admin-showcase.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/showcase/docs/#admin_theme 


<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

Comment: the project is java ee, and add primefaces.FONT_AWESOME to the web.xml, but now the following error appears:
 Warning: JSF1091: no MIME type found for file fa / fontawesome-webfont.eot. To solve it, add a MIME type assignment to the application's web.xml file.
Warning: JSF1091: no MIME type found for file fa / fontawesome-web

Comment: when I enter the mime type in the web.xml, the theme has no color

Comment: Yes, the theme is white based and it provides the foundations to admin-template, a layout based on AdminLTE. 

About the mime-types they should've added automatically if you use servlet 3.0 (see your web.xml) because admin-theme provides a web-fragment containing them, see here: https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-theme/blob/9c206c7af6104b0b1d9c18a428ffaf8886fdcfc2/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml#L14